# How to read VPD reg in PCI cards

Tags: c, driver, pci

I have a PCI card which I want to write driver for in C.

My problem is that I cannot find the serial number in the hardware which I really need.

I think every PCI card must have unique manufacturing ID perhaps similar to its barcode on the box.

I access bus and slot and base Add data that I need but cannot find a way to solve my problem.

The code for the solution is not usable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FLASH_BASE_ADDR 0x80000000
#define SNO_ADDR (FLASH_BASE_ADDR + 0x4C)


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sno, i;

    sno = *(int *)SNO_ADDR;

    printf("The serial number is %d.\n", sno);

    printf("\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

This code was for specific device and unusable in public task.
Now I see VPD can help me. Please tell me how can I read this data.

Comment: Why is your code not usable?

Comment: You cannot naively acess harware registers from a user program. You need a driver to do that. But that's probably beyond your scope for the moment.

Comment: Exactly i dont know but i think this address is not general and cannot use for all pci device

Comment: Thanks michaeal i use this driver for real time operating system and load on it my driver work properly but one of important section is mine hardware manufacturing id

Comment: @Hessan Well, writing a driver from scratch is a very large task, even just getting the serial number is a way too big task for a question here on stackoverflow, On the other hand, if you are using a particular operating system (are you ?)  that OS might already have a framework for writing PCI drivers, alleviating you from a few months of work

Comment: I wrote driver and device function correctly work My frameware use c code and some top level setting and dosent eny directly function to find serial number i see that code to find Ethernet pci cards serial number

Comment: Just i need to know address of this register

Answer (score 2):

There is no requirement for a PCI card to have a software-accessible serial number at all. And I have worked with a number of cards that did not have serial numbers (or at least such a thing was not documented in the data sheet). So the location and access method for this serial number (if it exists) will be completely device-specific.

For an Ethernet card, specifically, you can typically read its "burned-in" MAC address and use that as a proxy for a serial number since it is supposed to be unique. (I say "typically" because there is no PCI *requirement* that an Ethernet card have a burned-in MAC. However, I've never seen one that did not.)

Typically the MAC address will be stored in an EEPROM or similar device on the card, and there is a mechanism for reading data from the EEPROM through device registers located in one of the card's PCI BAR regions. However, the exact location of the MAC address and method for accessing it (again assuming it has one) is also device-specific.

Comment: Thanks gil. yes serial number isn't require for driver in typically work but for my purpose must i find it. my pci card isn't Ethernet for using mac. recently i find the keyword "VPD" i guess its my solution.  i try find a way to access it. Any one use that?

Comment: A web search using elements of the code you posted suggests that you obtained the code from https://www.moxa.com/support/faq/faq_detail.aspx?id=251. That page, however, applies to a particular set of devices made by that manufacturer: the UC-7110 and UC-7112. Those are small embedded computers, and are not PCI cards.

Comment: VPD is a datastore contained in some hardware, but again is very device-specific. Without identifying the particular device you're interested in, no one will be able to help you. And even if you do, any answer would only apply to that single device type.

Comment: That's it. i work now on "cp-132 ul" and as soon as on other board not same as it. i think must where general solution for most of them